# How to set Timeout for sending email using django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, email

I'm trying to set a timeout for sending email with Django. I'm using django 1.7.3 and python v2.7.6. My aproach was follow the django documentation in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#smtp-backend). So what i did was create a custom email backend by creating a file named myemailbackend.py on django/core/mail/backends folder with the following code:

```
from django.core.mail.backends import smtp

class MyEmailBackend(smtp.EmailBackend):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs.setdefault('timeout', 3) #this is 3 secs, i believe.
      super(MyEmailBackend, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

After that in my settings.py i set my EMAIL_BACKEND:

```
# Email setup

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.base.myemailbackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
# EMAIL_TIMEOUT = 3  # 3 sec, this would be great but i notice that this is not possible since that backend stmp.py doesn't expect to get "EMAIL_TIMEOUT" var.
```

After i runserver i've noticed that this doesn't seem to work, i notice to that myemailbackend.py didn't was compile.
What am i'm missing? How can i set a timeout for send email, afterall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is named `myemailbackend.py` in the folder `django/core/mail/backends`, then your setting would be

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.myemailbackend.MyEmailBackend'
```

that being said, it is a bad idea to place your code into a Django folder. It is better to place this in an app (say, `my_app/mymailbackend.py`) so that it will not be affected by Django reinstalls and/or upgrades.

Answer (score 7):

Django has a setting: [EMAIL_TIMEOUT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#email-timeout)