# How to explain django that my custom backend is inside of my app?

Tags: python, django, email, backend

According to the answer made on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696031/how-to-set-timeout-for-sending-email-using-django). It occurs a new issue about how can i define a custom email backend inside my application.

So in my app files i created an folder for my backends settings and inside of it i pasted myemailbackend.py where i define all my custom email backend settings.

After that, how can i say to Django that my app is inside of my app? 
How can i point that location so Django understands where to get such file..

`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'myapp.myemailbackend.MyEmailBackend`'
 something like this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly. If you have a `myemailbackend.py` in your `myapp` directory, the setting would be:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'myapp.myemailbackend.MyEmailBackend'
```

Note that this assumes that you have added `myapp` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: strange, i put like that but nothing happen..  i create a folder inside my app  called "backend"  which makes the definition different : like this:
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'myapp.backend.myemailbackend.MyEmailBackend' 
but it doenst seem to work like it did on django core. I notice that if you place it on the root of your application works.

Comment: Not all directories are Python packages. Did you put an (empty) `__init__.py` file inside your `backend` directory?

Comment: Yes, is that.. I didn't know the "\_\_init_\_.py" meaning. it works now! Thanks a lot for your two prompt answers.

Comment: You're welcome. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages for an explanation of `__init__.py`